# Flutter how to pass array and show in other widget

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a list of arrays i need to pass it to the other stateful widget and show the array there

This is my function code which retrieve data from API

```
  Future<List> doSomeAsyncStuff() async {
    final storage = new FlutterSecureStorage();
    String value = await storage.read(key: 'Cnic');
    print(value);

    String url = 'http://api.php?offset=0&limit=1&cnic=${value}' ;
    final msg = jsonEncode({"cnic": value});
    Map<String,String> headers = {'Content-Type':'application/json'};

    String token = value;
    final response = await http.get(url);

    var Data = json.decode(response.body);
    print(Data);

    var familyMembers = Data["records"][0]["family_members"];
    print(familyMembers);
    for (var familyMember in familyMembers){ //prints the name of each family member
      print(familyMember["name"]);
      print(familyMember["gender"]);
    }

  }
```

As you can see there is 2 list familyMember["name"] and familyMember["gender"] i need to pass it to statefulwidget

I am simple passing it like this

```
                        Navigator.push(
                            context,
                            MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => PersonalPage(familyMember["name"], familyMember["gender"])),
                        );
```

This is my other stateful widget I need to show the array of name and gender here

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class PersonalPage extends StatefulWidget {
  final String name;
  final String gender;
  PersonalPage(this.name, this.gender);

  @override
  _PersonalPageState createState() => _PersonalPageState();
}

class _PersonalPageState extends State<PersonalPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Text('I need to print name and gender here ')
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

flut

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing wrong you are passing list and in stateful widget you mention its a string you can do something like this

```
  List<String> familyMemberName = [];
  List<String> familyMemberGender = [];


  Future<List> doSomeAsyncStuff() async {
    final storage = new FlutterSecureStorage();
    String value = await storage.read(key: 'Cnic');
    print(value);

    String url = 'http://api.php' ;
    final msg = jsonEncode({"cnic": value});
    Map<String,String> headers = {'Content-Type':'application/json'};

    String token = value;
    final response = await http.get(url);

    var Data = json.decode(response.body);
    print(Data);

    var familyMembers = Data["records"][0]["family_members"];
    print(familyMembers);
    for (var familyMember in familyMembers){ 
      familyMemberName.add(familyMember["name"]);
      familyMemberGender.add(familyMember["gender"]);
      print(familyMemberName);
    }

  }
```

and in you personal widget like this

```
import "package:flutter/material.dart";

class PersonalPage extends StatefulWidget {
  final List<String> names;
  final List<String> relation;

  PersonalPage(this.names,this.relation);
  @override
  _PersonalPageState createState() => _PersonalPageState();
}

class _PersonalPageState extends State<PersonalPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(

        body:
        ListView.builder( //use ListView here to show all the names and genders
            itemCount: widget.names.length,
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context,int index){
              return Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10, right: 10, bottom: 10, top: 10),
                child: Card(
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
                    child: Column(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Row(
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Text('Name:', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.blue, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),),
                            Text(widget.names[index])
                          ],
                        ),
                        Row(
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Text('Gender:', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.blue, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),),
                            Text(widget.genders[index])
                          ],
                        ),

                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              );
            })
    );
  }
}
```

Sorry i test code so thats why i add it in card

Answer (score 1):

Try this and change your code as per this: As your First Page code is missing I have created a dummy forst Page.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(
    title: 'My APP',
    home: FirstRoute(),
  ));
}

class FirstRoute extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('List of ....'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: RaisedButton(
          child: Text('Open details'),
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.push(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => PersonalPage("NAME","GENDER")),
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class PersonalPage extends StatefulWidget {
  final String name;
  final String gender;
  PersonalPage(this.name, this.gender);

  @override
  _PersonalPageState createState() => _PersonalPageState();
}

class _PersonalPageState extends State<PersonalPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Row(
          children : [
            Text(widget.name),
            Text(widget.gender),
            
          ]
        )
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: i try like this but its showing this error when I am passing it The method '[]' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: []("name")

Comment: alsi i hide the api please remove it from answer thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

```
Text(widget.name)
Text(widget.gender)
```

or

```
Text("My name is ${widget.name} and my gender is ${widget.gender}")
```

Comment: i try like this but its showing this error when I am passing it The method '[]' was called on null. Receiver: null Tried calling: []("name")